After install of UBUNTU-24.04 - No bootable device
I have an old computer (2010-08), based upon "Intel Desktop board D510M0" using the Atom-processor. I have had an older version of Ubuntu-server, vs 18 something I think, that worked fine. But now I wanted to install the latest version but failed. Then I tried to install the desktop version instead so I could, from the usb-stick, se what disk-layout looked like.
The server version had all partition created but they where all empty. Now after I tried the desktop version, with same failure, this time I could see that the partitions contained data.
I also tested changing some parameters in the BIOS-setup ie. UEFI/BIOS but it didn't help
I have now also tried the "Boot-repair" software to fix it but when it finished I got the message: "Still no GRUB".
So I'm totally stuck.
This is the report from "Boot-Repair":

============================= Boot Repair Summary ==============================

User choice:

Is there RAID on this computer? no


==================== blkid (filtered) before lvm activation ====================

/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv: UUID="49c7f53a-4406-4a04-a814-4603d1247016" BLOCK_SIZE="4096" TYPE="ext4"
/dev/sda2: UUID="d13d8e6a-19c1-46a0-ac70-f09a771764b3" BLOCK_SIZE="4096" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="54f8acb8-8aa3-43c9-8008-d12fb262becd"
/dev/sdb1: LABEL="BOOT-REPAIR" UUID="6674-21C5" BLOCK_SIZE="512" TYPE="vfat" PARTUUID="38dc5ce4-01"
/dev/sdc: UUID="fa6a7bae-2551-4110-8b5c-03cf183e1aad" BLOCK_SIZE="4096" TYPE="ext4"
/dev/sda3: UUID="iBjhFe-HuDa-nBkj-lyoz-MqR1-PDNI-9YiZvg" TYPE="LVM2_member" PARTUUID="f0fafaa9-1a9e-47ee-8ead-3c7ee04cd9c8"
/dev/sda1: PARTUUID="e32661e0-2dee-44de-beda-a8341c270180"


================================ LVM activation ================================

modprobe dm-mod  
vgscan --mknodes
  Found volume group "ubuntu-vg" using metadata type lvm2
vgchange -ay
  1 logical volume(s) in volume group "ubuntu-vg" now active
lvscan
  ACTIVE            '/dev/ubuntu-vg/ubuntu-lv' [<463.76 GiB] inherit
blkid -g



Default settings: ______________________________________________________________

The default repair of the Boot-Repair utility would purge (in order to enable-lvm) and reinstall the grub2 of
mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv into the MBR of sda,
using the following options:  sda2/boot
Grub-efi would not be selected by default because no ESP detected.
Additional repair would be performed: unhide-bootmenu-10s

User settings: _________________________________________________________________

[dmraid -sa -c] no
[dmraid -sa -c] raid
[dmraid -sa -c] disks
/dev/sdc (/dev/sda) has unknown type. Please report this message to boot.repair@gmail.com
[dmraid -sa -c] no
[dmraid -sa -c] raid
[dmraid -sa -c] disks

=================== /boot detected. Please check the options.
The settings chosen by the user will purge (in order to enable-lvm) and reinstall the grub2 of
mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv into the MBR of sda,
using the following options:  sda2/boot
Grub-efi will not be selected by default because no ESP detected.
Additional repair will be performed: unhide-bootmenu-10s


/boot added in mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv/fstab
Mount /dev/sda2 on /mnt/boot-sav/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv/boot
chroot /mnt/boot-sav/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv apt-get -y update
Running in chroot, ignoring command 'start'
Purge the GRUB of /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv
grub-pc available

0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 87 not upgraded.
DEBCHECK debOK, grub-pc
DEBCHECK debOK
Please type: sudo chroot "/mnt/boot-sav/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv" dpkg --configure -ansudo chroot "/mnt/boot-sav/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv" apt-get install -fynsudo chroot "/mnt/boot-sav/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv" apt-get install -y lvm2nsudo chroot "/mnt/boot-sav/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv" apt-get purge --allow-remove-essential -y grub-com*nsudo chroot "/mnt/boot-sav/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv" apt-get purge --allow-remove-essential -y grub2-com*nsudo chroot "/mnt/boot-sav/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv" apt-get purge --allow-remove-essential -y shim-signednsudo chroot "/mnt/boot-sav/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv" apt-get purge --allow-remove-essential -y grub-common:*nsudo chroot "/mnt/boot-sav/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv" apt-get purge --allow-remove-essential -y grub2-common:*n
Then type: sudo chroot "/mnt/boot-sav/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv" apt-get install -y grub-pc

Unhide GRUB boot menu in mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv/etc/default/grub

========== Reinstall the grub-pc of /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv ==========

chroot /mnt/boot-sav/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv grub-install --version
grub-install (GRUB) 2.12-1ubuntu7

==> Reinstall the GRUB of /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv into the MBR of /dev/sda

chroot /mnt/boot-sav/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv grub-install /dev/sda
Installing for i386-pc platform.
Installation finished. No error reported.

chroot /mnt/boot-sav/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv update-grub
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
File descriptor 63 (pipe:[36056]) leaked on vgs invocation. Parent PID 20699: /usr/sbin/grub-probe
File descriptor 63 (pipe:[36056]) leaked on vgs invocation. Parent PID 20699: /usr/sbin/grub-probe
File descriptor 63 (pipe:[36056]) leaked on vgs invocation. Parent PID 20704: /usr/sbin/grub-probe
File descriptor 63 (pipe:[36056]) leaked on vgs invocation. Parent PID 20704: /usr/sbin/grub-probe
File descriptor 63 (pipe:[36056]) leaked on vgs invocation. Parent PID 20708: /usr/sbin/grub-probe
File descriptor 63 (pipe:[36056]) leaked on vgs invocation. Parent PID 20708: /usr/sbin/grub-probe
File descriptor 63 (pipe:[36056]) leaked on vgs invocation. Parent PID 20713: /usr/sbin/grub-probe
File descriptor 63 (pipe:[36056]) leaked on vgs invocation. Parent PID 20713: /usr/sbin/grub-probe
File descriptor 63 (pipe:[36056]) leaked on vgs invocation. Parent PID 20752: /usr/sbin/grub-probe
File descriptor 63 (pipe:[36056]) leaked on vgs invocation. Parent PID 20752: /usr/sbin/grub-probe
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-6.8.0-39-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-6.8.0-39-generic
File descriptor 63 (pipe:[36056]) leaked on vgs invocation. Parent PID 20952: /usr/sbin/grub-probe
File descriptor 63 (pipe:[36056]) leaked on vgs invocation. Parent PID 20952: /usr/sbin/grub-probe
Adding boot menu entry for UEFI Firmware Settings ...

Boot successfully repaired.

You can now reboot your computer.


============================ Boot Info After Repair ============================

 => Grub2 (v2.00) is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda and looks at sector 2048 
    of the same hard drive for core.img. core.img is at this location and 
    looks for (,gpt2)/grub. It also embeds following components:
    
    modules
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    fshelp ext2 part_gpt biosdisk
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
 => Syslinux MBR (5.00 and higher) is installed in the MBR of /dev/sdb.

sda1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       BIOS Boot partition
    Boot sector type:  Grub2's core.img
    Boot sector info: 

sda2: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /grub/grub.cfg /grub/i386-pc/core.img

sda3: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       LVM2_member
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 

sdb1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       vfat
    Boot sector type:  SYSLINUX 6.04
    Boot sector info:  Syslinux looks at sector 16408 of /dev/sdb1 for its 
                       second stage. The integrity check of Syslinux failed. 
                       No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /boot/grub/grub.cfg /syslinux.cfg 
                       /efi/boot/bootx64.efi /efi/boot/grubx64.efi 
                       /efi/boot/mmx64.efi /ldlinux.sys

sdc: ___________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        


================================ 2 OS detected =================================

OS#1:   Ubuntu 24.04 LTS on mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv
OS#2:   Linux on sdc

================================ Host/Hardware =================================

CPU architecture: 64-bit
Video: Atom Processor D4xx/D5xx/N4xx/N5xx Integrated Graphics Controller from Intel Corporation
Live-session OS is Linuxmint 64-bit (Linux Mint 21.2, victoria, x86_64)

===================================== UEFI =====================================

BIOS/UEFI firmware: MOPNV10J.86A.0148.2009.1102.2315(0.0) from Intel Corp.
This live-session is in Legacy/BIOS/CSM mode (not in EFI mode).



============================= Drive/Partition Info =============================

Disks info: ____________________________________________________________________

sda : is-GPT,   hasBIOSboot,    has-noESP,  not-usb,    not-mmc, has-os,    no-wind,    2048 sectors * 512 bytes

Partitions info (1/3): _________________________________________________________

mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv    : is-os,    64, apt-get,    grub-pc ,   grub2,  grub-install,   no-grubenv, update-grub,    not-far
sda2    : no-os,    64, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  grubenv-ok, noupdategrub,   not-far
sdc : is-os,    64, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   not-far

Partitions info (2/3): _________________________________________________________

mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv    : isnotESP, fstab-without-efi,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot
sda2    : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot
sdc : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot

Partitions info (3/3): _________________________________________________________

mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv    : not--sepboot, no---boot,  fstab-has-bad-boot, not-sep-usr,    with--usr,  fstab-without-usr,  std-grub.d, sda
sda2    : is---sepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, sda
sdc : not--sepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    emptyusr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, sda

fdisk -l (filtered): ___________________________________________________________

Disk sda: 465.76 GiB, 500107862016 bytes, 976773168 sectors
Disk identifier: 147932AD-E6D4-4EC3-84E3-804C2923C531
       Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
sda1     2048      4095      2048     1M BIOS boot
sda2     4096   4198399   4194304     2G Linux filesystem
sda3  4198400 976771071 972572672 463.8G Linux filesystem
Disk mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv: 463.76 GiB, 497956159488 bytes, 972570624 sectors
Disk sdb: 3.73 GiB, 4001366016 bytes, 7815168 sectors
Disk identifier: 0x38dc5ce4
     Boot Start     End Sectors  Size Id Type
sdb1  *     2048 7815111 7813064  3.7G  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)
Disk sdc: 1.92 GiB, 2061500416 bytes, 4026368 sectors

parted -lm (filtered): _________________________________________________________

sda:500GB:scsi:512:512:gpt:ATA WDC WD5000BEVT-8:;
1:1049kB:2097kB:1049kB:::bios_grub;
2:2097kB:2150MB:2147MB:ext4::;
3:2150MB:500GB:498GB:::;
sdb:4001MB:scsi:512:512:msdos:TDKMedia Trans-It Drive:;
1:1049kB:4001MB:4000MB:fat32::boot, lba;
sdc:2062MB:scsi:512:512:loop:Intel Value SSD:;
1:0.00B:2062MB:2062MB:ext4::;
mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv:498GB:dm:512:512:loop:Linux device-mapper (linear):;
1:0.00B:498GB:498GB:ext4::;

blkid (filtered): ______________________________________________________________

NAME                      FSTYPE      UUID                                   PARTUUID                             LABEL       PARTLABEL
sda                                                                                                                           
├─sda1                                                                       e32661e0-2dee-44de-beda-a8341c270180             
├─sda2                    ext4        d13d8e6a-19c1-46a0-ac70-f09a771764b3   54f8acb8-8aa3-43c9-8008-d12fb262becd             
└─sda3                    LVM2_member iBjhFe-HuDa-nBkj-lyoz-MqR1-PDNI-9YiZvg f0fafaa9-1a9e-47ee-8ead-3c7ee04cd9c8             
  └─ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv ext4        49c7f53a-4406-4a04-a814-4603d1247016                                                    
sdb                                                                                                                           
└─sdb1                    vfat        6674-21C5                              38dc5ce4-01                          BOOT-REPAIR 
sdc                       ext4        fa6a7bae-2551-4110-8b5c-03cf183e1aad                                                    

Mount points (filtered): _______________________________________________________

                                   Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv 423.3G   2% /mnt/boot-sav/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv
/dev/sda2                           1.7G   5% /mnt/boot-sav/sda2
/dev/sdb1                           1.3G  66% /cdrom
/dev/sdc                            1.7G   0% /mnt/boot-sav/sdc

Mount options (filtered): ______________________________________________________

/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv ext4            rw,relatime
/dev/sda2                         ext4            rw,relatime
/dev/sdb1                         vfat            ro,noatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro
/dev/sdc                          ext4            rw,relatime

============================== ls -R /dev/mapper/ ==============================

/dev/mapper:
control
ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv

======================== sda2/grub/grub.cfg (filtered) =========================

Ubuntu   49c7f53a-4406-4a04-a814-4603d1247016
### END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
UEFI Firmware Settings   uefi-firmware
### END /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###

==================== sda2: Location of files loaded by Grub ====================

           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)
   0.240421295 = 0.258150400    grub/grub.cfg                                  1
   0.231098175 = 0.248139776    grub/i386-pc/core.img                          1
   0.164299011 = 0.176414720    vmlinuz                                        1
   0.164299011 = 0.176414720    vmlinuz-6.8.0-39-generic                       1
   0.164299011 = 0.176414720    vmlinuz.old                                    1
   0.309558868 = 0.332386304    initrd.img                                     1
   0.309558868 = 0.332386304    initrd.img-6.8.0-39-generic                    1
   0.309558868 = 0.332386304    initrd.img.old                                 1

====================== sdb1/boot/grub/grub.cfg (filtered) ======================

Start Boot-Repair-Disk 64-bit
Start Boot-Repair-Disk 64-bit (compatibility mode)
UEFI Firmware Settings
Test memory

========================= sdb1/syslinux.cfg (filtered) =========================

DEFAULT loadconfig

LABEL loadconfig
  CONFIG /isolinux/isolinux.cfg
  APPEND /isolinux/

==================== sdb1: Location of files loaded by Grub ====================

           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)
            ?? = ??             boot/grub/grub.cfg                             1

================== sdb1: Location of files loaded by Syslinux ==================

           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)
            ?? = ??             syslinux.cfg                                   1
            ?? = ??             ldlinux.sys                                    1
sprunge.us ko ()


My old 2006 system would not install Ubuntu desktop. Server version installed and I was a bit surprised even Kubuntu installed but was slow as only 1.5GB of RAM. With external SSD worked very well. If you want desktop try lightweight flavor or server with just gui not full desktop with its apps. https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours
Light weight flavors:
Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, Budgie
Flavors of Ubuntu only come with three years of supported life (five years applies to Ubuntu Desktop, Ubuntu Server but not flavors)
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ServerGUI

This is not really an answer to my question, of course this computer is not fast but I had no problems with that when I run Ubuntu-18 server. This time, with UBUNTU-24 I'm not able to make an install that even start to boot. I'm pretty sure it has something to do with BIOS/UEFI. I think that it should be possible to fix in a way. But of course I have to be open for testing something else than ubuntu if necessary.

You mentioned Ubuntu desktop. If server only what tool are you using to create live installer? Since systems since 2012 are UEFI, many installers default to UEFI. You want BIOS/CSM/Legacy, not UEFI. Most that default to UEFI do have instructions on how to create a BIOS installer. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/UEFI-and-BIOS

My computer has UEFI enabled in BIOS and I tried using the UBUNTU-packages, which I downloaded, to install the server. I have tried 24.04, 22.04, 20.4, and also 18.10 but they use same type of installer so none worked for me but when I tested 16.04 it worked. That version used an older variant of installer. After that I upgraded to 18.10 and after that 20.04 and after that 22.04. 24.04 is not currently available for upgrading but I think I'm satisfied with 22.04 for the moment.
